# Query to check if there is a record of a certain ID in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make a query to check if there are records with the selected id.

Comment: you can try with a simple sql tutorial

Comment: Pretty sure this will be a dup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for existence of records you can use this code:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP(1) 1 FROM schema.table WHERE condition)
BEGIN
 SELECT field FROM schema.table WHERE condition;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 --do something for no records
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the support, I already have to start testing.
Greetings.

Comment: And if I want to do with it does not exist, I just add: not before: exist?

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM myTable
```

Will give you the first record of your table. If you get nothing back, there is no records in your table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Rows from myTable
```

Will give you how many records in the table. This should only be used when you need to know how many rows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will see my query to see that I can do it.

Greetings.

Comment: Using `*` is expensive, return just the fields you require.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DECLARE
   @ID INTEGER
SELECT
   @ID = 2 --enter ID you are looking for here

IF EXISTS
(SELECT TOP(1) ID, FieldName FROM MyTable WHERE ID = @ID)
BEGIN 
    SELECT 
        ID, 
        FieldName
    FROM
        MyTable
    WHERE ID = @ID
END

ELSE

BEGIN
    SELECT UserNote = 'No records match your search.'
END
```

Comment: When using `EXISTS` the `SELECT` doesn't need to return anything, you could just use `IF EXISTS
(SELECT TOP(1) NULL FROM MyTable WHERE ID = @ID)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNTOFROWS FROM TABLENAME WHERE <CONDITION>
```

EX:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUMBEROFSTUDENTS FROM STUDENTS WHERE STUDENT_GRADE = 'A'
```

Here,

`COUNT(*)` - Will give you number of rows which are satisfied (ex. `STUDENT_GRADE = 25`)

off course, `COUNTOFROWS` is optional and user defined name which you can define which is relative

Comment: Thanks for the help